# Javascript - IF sendo executado antes da hora

Tags: javascript, firebase

Amigos, poderiam me explicar e se possível, dar uma solução para o seguinte problema?

Meu `if` onde está escrito:

```
if(aux == 0)
{
    console.log("não encontrado");
}
```

Está sendo executado antes da verificação no firebase, isso somente na primeira vez que abro o aplicativo. Abaixo está o código da minha função:

```
var refUser = new Firebase("//endereçodofirebaseescondido");
var key;

function logar() {
  var aux = 0;
  var login = document.getElementById("form1").elements.namedItem("login").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("form1").elements.namedItem("senha").value;
  refUser.orderByChild("login").equalTo(login).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key();
    refUser.orderByChild("pass").equalTo(pass).on("child_added", function(snap) {
      aux = 1;
      console.log(pass);
      if (key == snap.key()) {
        console.log("senha e login conferem");
      } else {
        console.log("não encontrado");
      }
    });
  });
  if (aux == 0) {
    console.log("não encontrado");
  }
}
```

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é exatamente o problema. Você está achando estranho sair no log "não encontrado", é isso?

Comment: Isso. Clico no botão e ele automaticamente executa esse último if. Gostaria de uma solução para que esse if só fosse executado após a parte mais acima ser executada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você não entendeu um ponto fundamental do Javascript, que são as **funções assíncronas.**

Repare que o código que você quer que execute antes do `if` pertence a uma função anônima que você passou como parâmetro da chamada `on`. Esse código só vai ser executado quando o evento `child_added` ocorrer.

Tudo que está entre `refUser.` e o segundo `});` é um comando só (pense nisso como uma "linha" só). Esse comando todo simplesmente registra o que vai acontecer no futuro. Esse registro é instantâneo. Logo em seguida, o seu `if` vai rodar, porque ele vem logo depois desse comando. Não deu tempo ainda de acontecer o evento `child_added` que vai desencadear o código que você quer.

Seu código está muito confuso (sugiro que dê uma melhorada nos nomes das suas variáveis), então não dá pra sugerir uma nova versão, mas quando você entender exatamente como funcionam funções assíncronas, você vai ver que vai ter mudar seu jeito de pensar.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver! Usei um `setTimeout` para executar o if pouco tempo depois, fazendo com que dê tempo de executar o código mais acima.

Solução:

```
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                if(aux == 0)
                {
                    console.log("não encontrado");
                    alert("sem show");
                }
            }, 500)
```

Comment: Isso é uma má ideia. Não há garantias de que a chamada ao Firebase vai demorar exatamente isso. Sugiro que tente entender como funcionam chamadas assíncronas em vez de apelar para gambiarras com relógio.